# fail to install gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf

Tags: linux, gcc

I'm trying to install `gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf` at Ubuntu, but got the below error:

```
Reading package lists… Done Building dependency tree Reading state
information… Done E: Unable to locate package
gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf E: Couldn’t find any package by
glob ‘gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf’ E: Couldn’t find any
package by regex ‘gcc-4.7-multilib-arm-linux-gnueabihf’
```

Comment: Do you have universe enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the package looking for is probably named differently/has gotten a version upgrade

please next time run:

```
hostnamectl; # and give details about what os is used
```

try:

```
su - root; # become root
apt update; # update apt package database
apt search gnueabihf; # try to find a package that contains this string

hostnamectl; # tested on this system
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-9-amd64
Architecture: x86-64

apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf; # install gcc arm compiler
```

probably wanted to test cross compiling RUST "hello world" for ARM?

check out my article: https://dwaves.org/2019/09/27/compile-rust-hello-world-for-arm7/